# How can I speed up my wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, page-speed

My website is based on a Wordpress and I want to know why its loading metrics are so bad. What can I do practically?

I've already tried to use:

- Cloudflare
- W3 Total Cache
- Autoptimize
- EWWW Image Optimizer

Comment: What is it that's slowing down your site? There's a lot of factors involved. It could be server, too many plugins etc

Comment: They eliminated the link to my site, this is my speed test:
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/dL5gV/http://www.6dragonskungfu.com

I know the problems, I do not know how to solve them:

- Leverage browser caching
- Combine external JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

The most practical thing you can do is:

1. Optimize your images
2. Remove query strings from static resources (there's a plugin for this)
3. Set expire dates on your headers (I think you can do this with Cloudflare)
4. Choose your hosting provider wisely.

If you're hosting on a shared server somewhere like GoDaddy or Bluehost than there's not much you can do. I would suggest looking into a managed VPS host like Cloudways.

Comment: I use a2hosting, it is not so bad, the bigger problem is with WordPress and its plug-ins / themes that limit my control on external requests and with image resizing... 

this is my speed test: tools.pingdom.com/#!/dL5gV/http://www.6dragonskungfu.com